# Formik Default Values UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, formik

I am trying to prepopulate a Formik with JSON data. The data appears fine and it is returned. I have two issues.

I am using ASP.NET Core as the back end. Should I use values or initialValues as the variable? When I use initialValues, I get assign fields. The labels are still populated.

The labels are still populated, after I send a default value. All the fields are read only and I cannot edit them:

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
function OrdersToReporting() {

    const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState<OrdersToReportingViewModels>({ });

    useEffect(() => {
        agent.Settings.getOrdersSettings().then((userList) => {
            let solutionName = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get("SolutionName");
            let solutionWebsite = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get("SolutionWebsite");
            userList.data.SolutionName = solutionName;
            userList.data.SolutionWebsite = solutionWebsite;
            setInitialValues(userList.data);
        });
    }, []);

    const handleSubmit = async (
        values: any,
        { resetForm, setErrors, setStatus, setSubmitting }: any
    ) => {
        try {
            await timeOut(1500);
            agent.Settings.saveOrdersSettings(values);
            resetForm();
            setStatus({ sent: true });
            setSubmitting(false);
        } catch (error: any) {
            setStatus({ sent: false });
            setErrors({ submit: error.message });
            setSubmitting(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
            {({
                errors,
                handleBlur,
                handleChange,
                handleSubmit,
                isSubmitting,
                touched,
                values,
                status,
            }) => (
               
                        {isSubmitting ? (
                            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" my={6}>
                                <CircularProgress />
                            </Box>
                        ) : (
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <Grid container spacing={6}>
                                        <Grid item md={6}>
                                            <TextField
                                                name="SolutionName"
                                                label="Solution Name"
                                                value={initialValues.SolutionName}
                                                fullWidth
                                                onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                onChange={handleChange}
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                my={2}
                                            />

                                            <TextField
                                                name="SolutionWebsite"
                                                label="Solution Website"
                                                value={initialValues.SolutionWebsite}
                                                fullWidth
                                                onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                onChange={handleChange}
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                my={2}
                                            />

                                        <TextField
                                            name="lastDownloadUtc"
                                            label="Last Download Date Start"
                                                value={initialValues.LastDownloadUtc}
                                            fullWidth
                                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            my={2}
                                        />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item md={6}>
                                            <TextField
                                                name="lastDownloadUtcEnd"
                                                label="Last Download Date End"
                                                value={initialValues.LastDownloadUtcEnd}
                                                fullWidth
                                                onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                onChange={handleChange}
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                my={2}
                                            />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>

                             

                                <Button
                                    type="submit"
                                    variant="contained"
                                    color="primary"
                                    mt={3}
                                >
                                    Save changes
                                </Button>
                            </form>
                        )}
                  
            )}
        </Formik>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your questions,

1. You should use `initialValues` to assign default values to your fields.

   since you are getting the data from some function, there might be a delay in setting initialValues. So pass `enableReinitialize={true}` in formik props.
2. You were not able to change the values because you set

   ```
   value={initialValues.fieldName} // always value will be this unless you change initialValues state
   ```

   for every textfield. Always this will be same even if you edit.

   Just remove the value property `formik` will handle it by default.